# Defining Cassandra IColumn class with new coming class Column

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cassandra

I'm having a problem,
first i was using **cassandra 1.2** and its **IColumn** class, which has been changed with **Column** in **cassandra 2.0**, now my question is, how i can replcae this ColumnClass in my **mapreduce** programm so that i won't get error.. what will be the method to retrieve 
from:

```
Mapper<ByteBuffer, SortedMap<ByteBuffer, IColumn>, Text, Text>
// and its retrieval is something like
for (IColumn cell : columns.values()) {
     colName = ByteBufferUtil.string(cell.name());
     String colValue = null;
     if (name.contains("int")) {
         colValue = String.valueOf(ByteBufferUtil.toInt(cell.value()));
}else{
        colValue = ByteBufferUtil.string(cell.value());
}
}
```

to

```
Mapper<ByteBuffer, SortedMap<ByteBuffer, Column>, Text, Text>
```

how i will retrieve the key,value from this?